controlling real robot through joystick
i am successfully created robot through urdf in ROS2 , and i am controlling the robot through joystick in gazebo (virtual mode). Now i have one real robot setup , including 2 nos of servo motor(400w) and dual axis drive , one battery 52Ah , wheels, etc.., right now i have to run the real robot using joystick like what i did in gazebo .. could you help me how to do that and provide any resources or sample code . it will help for me..........

First: How can you interface your robot, hardware/software?
Then, decide if you want to use ros2_control for your real setup.
If yes, start writing your custom hardware component.
Then you can change the gz_ros2_control to your custom hardware component and use the other nodes on top of it.

Thank you for your response........ I am beginner to this ros2 i am using 2 no's of 400 watts servo motors , one drive for controlling the motors, using modbus communication , is there any reference for this
